# How to start an activity from intent using broadcast?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using the code to call an intent in Android

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
String PACKAGE_NAME="com...."
intent.setPackage(PACKAGE_NAME);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
getApplication().startActivity(intent);
```

Unfortunately, in some case, I do not know the PACKAGE_NAME. So, another method is using broadcast. How can I use it? Thanks all

Comment: What do you mean "another method is using the broadcast"?

Comment: It means we do not need setPackage function but still can call the intent

Comment: You never needed a package name. Use a Context

Comment: Thanks cricket_007. But I am calling the native app in Android, such as SVOICE, bixby app....in Android 7.0

Comment: @user8264 "It means ..." Then don't use setPackage!

Comment: @user8264 "Thanks cricket_007..." If you don't specify the package, the user will be shown a list of available apps.

Comment: So I am looking for another way to do it. DO you have it

Comment: How do you know what you should run?

Comment: I got the suggestion from another guy. I do not know it

Answer (score 0):

You **cant** call Activity directly if you dont know **package** and **name** of that Activity.

Since you dont know package and Activity name you can only **ask** OS to show all possible variants for your Intent Action. In most cases user click "always open this app for this action" what means that you will directly open another app.

So in your case your code should looks like

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//dont forget to check if user has at least one application for your Intent Action
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Is `sendIntent` is `intent`?

Comment: If I am in service. so it will be `getApplicationContext.startActivity(intent)`? I will check it and let you know

Comment: @ye getAppicationContext()

Comment: @user8264 Are you sure you have applications which support ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND? Did you try to log inside !=null block?